# Product of 2d array x and y value and show array of products in 1d with Haskell

Tags: haskell

How can I create a function for doing this:

```
[(3,4), (6,5)...]
```

after production return to

```
[12,30]
```

Comment: Your input is a list of tuples, not a 2d array. Is that your actual input, or do you really have a list of lists e.g. [[1,2],[3,4]..]?

Comment: @shree.pat18 I far from this terminology. You are right It is a list of tuples.

Comment: voting to close

Answer (score 2):

You can use the map function to do this, like so:

```
map (\(a,b) -> a * b) yourinput
```

This pattern matches the two elements of each tuple in the list and then multiplies them.

Comment: Also known as `map (uncurry (*)) yourinput`. And also worth considering: to write it as a list comprehension, `[a*b | (a,b) <- yourinput]`.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I was struggling with the point-free form on this